# CATransition with CIFilter doesn't work first time,works second time

Tags: cocoa, nsview, core-image, catransition, nsviewanimation

I want to add CATransition animation for NSView. I have the following code:

```
[contentView setWantsLayer:YES];
NSRect rect = [contentView bounds];

NSData *shadingBitmapData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"restrictedshine" ofType:@"tiff"]]; // took from Apple's example
NSBitmapImageRep *shadingBitmap = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:shadingBitmapData] autorelease];
CIImage *inputShadingImage = [[[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapImageRep:shadingBitmap] autorelease];
CIFilter *transitionFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIRippleTransition"];
[transitionFilter setDefaults];
[transitionFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:NSMidX(rect) Y:NSMidY(rect)] forKey:@"inputCenter"];
[transitionFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:rect.origin.x Y:rect.origin.y Z:rect.size.width W:rect.size.height] forKey:@"inputExtent"];
[transitionFilter setValue:inputShadingImage forKey:@"inputShadingImage"];

CATransition *presentAnimation = [CATransition animation];
[presentAnimation setFilter:transitionFilter];
[presentAnimation setDuration:1.0];
[presentAnimation setDelegate:self];

[contentView setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:presentAnimation forKey:@"subviews"]];
// maybe there are memory leaks in this code, don't bother at this moment
```

The problem is:

1. I execute this code.
2. I do `[[contentView animator] addSubview:mySubview];` for the first time, it does not work. View just appears. `CATransition` delegate methods are called, but `finished` flag is NO (false).
3. I remove view by `[mySubview removeFromSuperview];` and it removes with animation, `finished` flag = YES (true).
4. I repeat steps 2 and 3 and it works with animation. Step 2 now tells that animation was `finished` (YES). Works as expected.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved.

First of all: `[contentView setWantsLayer:YES];`, and this must be set before performing animations. Better place for this are `awakeFromNib` or `init` methods, or something like this. You need to enable Core Animation on `contentView`, perform UI drawing (I mean allow your app to do this), and only then perform animations. In my case I enabled Core Animation and performed animation immediately, and that's why it did not work for me.